# My image is not displayed and the alternative is displayed

Tags: html, image, web

I am trying to build a portfolio website, with a moving gallery but the image is not displayed, it shows the alternative image instead. Any help is appreciated.Here is the code:

```
<div class="section1">
          <img class="imgr"src="photo_1.jpg" alt="nothing">
        </div>
```

I even copied the relative path from Vscode, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It must be the path to the image. Try replacing "photo_1.jpg" with "./photo_1.jpg".